# Solitaire in C- problem with card symbols

Tags: c, windows, ascii

I am an engineering student. As an exam test, the professor asks us to implement solitaire in C. Being a beginner, I'm having some difficulty displaying the suits of the cards. If I convert the decimal number to an ASCII symbol, the output returns a question mark "?"; Is there any way to show the sign instead of the question mark?
I'm trying to get a more graphic symbol, using ASCII. Here are the codes that I have compiled. During compilation, it does not return any errors but the executable is empty; it does not return anything. The compiler I'm using is Dev-C ++.
Could it be that my console font doesn't support this character set? If yes, is it possible to modify it to make it compatible?

**Test 1:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef enum { cuori, quadri, fiori, picche }  semi;
typedef enum { coperta, scoperta, eliminata }  status;

typedef struct _card
{
    int valore;
    semi seme;
    status stato;
} card;


const wchar_t visSemi[][2] = { L"\u2665", L"\u2660", L"\u2663", L"\u2666" };


void visCard(card *c)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    if (c->stato == scoperta)
    {
        switch (c->valore)
        {
        case 1:
            printf ("A\n");
            break;
        case 11:
            printf ("J\n");
            break;
        case 12:
            printf("Q\n");
            break;
        case 13:
            printf("K\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("\n", visSemi[c->seme]);
    }
    else
    {
        if (c->stato == coperta)
            printf("??\n");
    }

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
}

int main()
{
    card pila[8] = {
                     {  1, cuori, scoperta },
                     { 11, quadri, scoperta },
                     { 12, fiori, scoperta },
                     { 13, picche, eliminata },
                     {  1, quadri, scoperta },
                     { 11, fiori, scoperta },
                     { 12, picche, scoperta },
                     { 13, cuori, coperta },
                   };

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        visCard(&pila[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Test 2 (more generally):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main (void){
  _setmode(_fileno(stdout),_O_U16TEXT);

  wprintf(L"\x043a\x043e\x0448\x043a\x0430\x65e5\x672c\x56fd\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have a problem with displaying the symbols for the cards, you  might strip all the other stuff from your code that is not related to that problem.

Comment: You mention ASCII, but then you show code examples using Unicode. The ASCII values that represent Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds and Spades are 03, 04, 05, and 06 respectively.  If that doesn't work in your console, maybe you should focus on the game itself, and worry about the visual finesse later.  Using the first letter of each suit or the full name ought to be fine, unless your professor has specified otherwise.

Comment: I'm on windows, but using Visual Studio as a compiler. The usage of `_setmode` in `viscard` crashes for me on the printf. However, using it separately with wprintf and testing each of the characters in `visSemi ` works fine, whereas without `_setmode` only question marks are displayed.

Comment: Note: I listed the values in the wrong order, and it's too late to edit my comment.  It is Hearts (03 / ETX), Diamonds (04 / EOT), Clubs (05 / ENQ), Spades (06 / ACK).  See https://theasciicode.com.ar for the full ASCII table.  Understand that these are actually control characters, and not all consoles will display them.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code but always the same error. returns only "?"

Comment: Yes, the professor requires the display of symbols, not letters. I'm trying to change compiler, as you recommended Visual Studio and see if it goes there. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! What console are you using to run the program?
There seems to be some confusion between ascii and UTF/Unicode. The basic ascii encoding does not have any symbols like the one's you're looking for. Extended versions of ascii might, I'm not sure, but if you want to display card suit symbols it seems easier to use UTF, if thats an option in your case.

You'll have to make sure that the console you are running you're program in is using UTF, and use the \xhhhh sequence to print the appropriate character.

Answer (score 2):

This use of `printf()`:

```
printf("\n", visSemi[c->seme]);
```

is incorrect by its intention, although the argument of `visSemi[c->seme]` is evaluated but ignored:

> "*If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined. If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.*"
>
> Source: C18, §7.21.6.1/2

To print a `wchar_t` with `printf()` is not correct.

Use `wprintf()` to print a `wchar_t`:

```
wprintf(L"%lc\n", visSemi[c->seme]);
```

instead.